# How to add one list to one cell at a time in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops

> I have a for loop which prints a list of hex strings for each iteration
>
> ```
> for i in range(0, 10):
>     print([str(hex(i))[::2], str(hex(i*10))[::2], str(hex(i+10))[::2]])
> ```
>
> the output is
>
> ```
> ['00', '00', '0a']
> ['01', '0a', '0b']
> ['02', '01', '0c']
> ['03', '01', '0d']
> ['04', '02', '0e']
> ['05', '03', '0f']
> ['06', '03', '01']
> ['07', '04', '01']
> ['08', '05', '01']
> ['09', '05', '01']
> ```
>
> I want to read the lists into one cell at a time such that the  dataframe should look like this
>
> | idx | NEWcoL |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | ['00', '00', '0a'] |
> | 2 | ['01', '0a', '0b'] |
> | 3 | ['02', '01', '0c'] |
> | 4 | ['03', '01', '0d'] |
> | 5 | ['04', '02', '0e'] |
> | 6 | ['05', '03', '0f'] |
> | 7 | ['06', '03', '01'] |
> | 8 | ['07', '04', '01'] |
> | 9 | ['08', '05', '01'] |
> | 10 | ['09', '05', '01'] |

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
my_list=[]
for i in range(0, 10):
    my_list.append([str(hex(i))[::2], str(hex(i*10))[::2], str(hex(i+10))[::2]])
df=pd.DataFrame({'NEWcoL':my_list}).reset_index(names='idx')
```

**Output**:

```
   idx        NEWcoL
0    0  [00, 00, 0a]
1    1  [01, 0a, 0b]
2    2  [02, 01, 0c]
3    3  [03, 01, 0d]
4    4  [04, 02, 0e]
5    5  [05, 03, 0f]
6    6  [06, 03, 01]
7    7  [07, 04, 01]
8    8  [08, 05, 01]
9    9  [09, 05, 01]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[0], columns=['NEWcoL'])
for i in range(0, 10):
    df.loc[i, 'NEWcoL']=[str(hex(i))[::2], str(hex(i*10))[::2], str(hex(i+10))[::2]]

df.index = np.arange(1, len(df) + 1)
df.index.names = ['idx']


           NEWcoL
idx              
1    [00, 00, 0a]
2    [01, 0a, 0b]
3    [02, 01, 0c]
4    [03, 01, 0d]
5    [04, 02, 0e]
6    [05, 03, 0f]
7    [06, 03, 01]
8    [07, 04, 01]
9    [08, 05, 01]
10   [09, 05, 01]
```

Answer (score 0):

`hex` bulitin function already returns a string representation of an integer, no need to `str` additionally. Here's simple one-liner:

```
In [362]: df = pd.DataFrame({'idx':range(1, 11), 'newcol':[[hex(i)[::2], hex(i*10)[::2], hex(i+10)[::2]] for i in range(10)]})

In [363]: df
Out[363]: 
   idx        newcol
0    1  [00, 00, 0a]
1    2  [01, 0a, 0b]
2    3  [02, 01, 0c]
3    4  [03, 01, 0d]
4    5  [04, 02, 0e]
5    6  [05, 03, 0f]
6    7  [06, 03, 01]
7    8  [07, 04, 01]
8    9  [08, 05, 01]
9   10  [09, 05, 01]
```